# File created with Android mediastore is not visible anymore after application reinstallation

Tags: android

When I create a file with MediaStore to the Android "downloads" folder, if I uninstall my application and reinstall it again, this last does not see the file previously created (even if it's the same app). I know that there are some limitation with Android 11 (which I use) but maybe the problem is coming from my code.

Here below the code to create the file :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns.Title, filename + "." + extension);
values.Put(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Downloads.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName, filename);
values.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, "text/plain");
values.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/" + subfolder + "/");
Android.Net.Uri urivolume = MediaStore.Downloads.GetContentUri(MediaStore.VolumeExternalPrimary);
uri = ct.ContentResolver.Insert(urivolume, values); 
Stream outputStream = ct.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(uri);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
outputStream.Write(bytes);
outputStream.Close();
```

And here below the code to find the created file :

```
Android.Net.Uri uriVolume;
               Android.Net.Uri uriResult;
               string[] projection;

               uriVolume = MediaStore.Downloads.GetContentUri(MediaStore.VolumeExternalPrimary);

               projection = new string[] { MediaStore.DownloadColumns.Id };

               Android.Database.ICursor cursor = ct.ContentResolver.Query(uriVolume, projection, MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DisplayName + " LIKE ?", new string[] { filename + "." + extension }, null);
               cursor.MoveToFirst();
               if (cursor.Count > 0)
               {
                   int columnId = cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                   long fileId = cursor.GetLong(columnId);
                   uriResult = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uriVolume.ToString() + "/" + fileId);
                   cursor.Close();
                   return uriResult;
               }
```

This last has a cursor.count equals to 0 after reinstalled the application (however the file is existing).

I am using Xamarin for Android.

Comment: It is unclear which help you ask. But for what you described: yes that is normal behaviour on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: What help I am asking for is to know if it's a normal Android behaviour that creating a file with an app, uninstall an app, reinstall it makes the created file not accessible anymore by the app or if it could be to a bad code from me. So by your answer, I guess that it's a normal Android behaviour and I can't do anything against it. Am I right ? If so, where can we store data that must be persistent even after application reinstallation ?

Comment: It is normal behaviour. And the data is persistant. But not reachable/accessable using mediastore. You can let the user select the file though using for instance ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: I will test that. Thanks !